# Lodash Equivalent to C# LINQ GroupBy and Select in TypeScript

Tags: c#, linq, typescript

I'm trying to find a way to do the equivalent of `.GroupBy(key => key.IdShopItem).Select(item => item.Single());` in typescript.

I've tried this `LinQ for TypeScript` https://github.com/kutyel/linq.ts but it seems there's a bug and also it does not support this so far.

Also I've tried with `lodash` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy, but I had no success.

How can I achieve this please? Already spend a couple of hours on this...

Comment: Did you try using lodash uniq?

Comment: Self promotion: You could try my library [loq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loq)  for `loq(someIterable).groupBy(item=>item.prop).select(g=>g.single())`. The [tests](https://github.com/biggyspender/loq/blob/master/test/library.spec.js) will give you an idea of what's available.

Comment: ...or even `loq(someIterable).distinctBy(item=>item.prop)`

Comment: @Bayeni thanks. Something like this? `_(list).chain()
.where({ Id: parent.Id })
.groupBy(parent.IdShopItem.toString())
.uniq()` How do I return the initial type of `list` ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Disclaimer: I wrote this library

You could use the javascript [loq](https://github.com/biggyspender/loq) library to achieve this. Here's a snippet to get you on your way:

```js
var list = [
  {name:"dog",type:"animal"},
  {name:"cat",type:"animal"},
  {name:"snake",type:"animal"},
  {name:"table",type:"furniture"},
  {name:"chair",type:"furniture"},
];
var filtered = loq(list).distinctBy(item => item.type);
console.log(filtered.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/biggyspender/loq/67db7014/lib/loq.min.js"></script>
```

...or with requirejs

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        loq: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/biggyspender/loq/67db7014/lib/loq.min'
    }
});

require(['loq'], function(loq){
  var list = [
    {name:"dog",type:"animal"},
    {name:"cat",type:"animal"},
    {name:"snake",type:"animal"},
    {name:"table",type:"furniture"},
    {name:"chair",type:"furniture"},
  ];
  var filtered = loq(list).distinctBy(item => item.type);
  console.log(filtered.toArray());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.js"></script>
```

It's a relatively complete reimplementation of LINQ-to-objects on iterables (objects that implement `Symbol.iterator`) with a few extra goodies (such as `distinctBy`). Take a look at the [tests](https://github.com/biggyspender/loq/blob/master/test/library.spec.js) to see other uses.

Comment: `import { loq } from "loq";` doesnt seem to work, am I missing something?

Comment: IIRC it should just be `import loq from "loq"`

Comment: @GeraldHughes ... Indeed, take a look: https://repl.it/repls/IntrepidTraumaticPublishers

Comment: I already tried this, for some reason it does not work for me. I'm using requirejs, and I get this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`. Thanks for your response

Comment: @GeraldHughes Thats strange, because it does have a UMD loader. I added a version that uses requirejs (but no es6 import syntax). It might help. I don't use requirejs, so this is as far as I can take this. Good luck.